# JDBC: Inserting Date values into MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date, jdbc

I would like to know how to set Date values to MySQL database, using Java JDBC. Following is my code.

```
 String lastCrawlDate = "2014-01-28"
 PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement("insert into JsonData (last_crawl_date) values(?))");

 p.setDate(1, Date.valueOf(lastCrawlDate));
```

As you can see, the `lastCrawlDate` is a `String` and in the format of `yyyy/mm/dd`.

Following is how my table looks like and how the `Date` field is defined.

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: What part fails in your existing code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) provides the methods [`setDate(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate%28int,%20java.sql.Date%29), [`setTimestamp(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp%29), and [`setTime(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTime%28int,%20java.sql.Time%29) to replace placeholders (`?`) with date type fields. Use them

```
String lastCrawlDate = "2014-01-28";
Date utilDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(lastCrawlDate);
// because PreparedStatement#setDate(..) expects a java.sql.Date argument
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime()); 

Connection con = ...;
PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement("insert into JsonData (last_crawl_date) values(?))");
p.setDate(1, sqlDate);
```

Answer (score 4):

Immediately insert your date as a string

```
p.setString(1, lastCrawlDate);
```

Exactly as

```
insert into Table1 (last_crawl_date) values ('2014-01-28');
```

> MySQL recognizes DATE values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in either 'YYYY-MM-DD' or 'YY-MM-DD' format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted: Any punctuation character may be used
>     as the delimiter between date parts. For example, '2012-12-31',
>     '2012/12/31', '2012^12^31', and '2012@12@31' are equivalent.
> - As a string with no delimiters in either 'YYYYMMDD' or 'YYMMDD' format, provided that the string makes sense as a date. For example,
>     '20070523' and '070523' are interpreted as '2007-05-23', but '071332'
>     is illegal (it has nonsensical month and day parts) and becomes
>     '0000-00-00'.
> - As a number in either YYYYMMDD or YYMMDD format, provided that the number makes sense as a date. For example, 19830905 and 830905 are
>     interpreted as '1983-09-05'.

Using this approach, you can write a method to obtain a string from a given Date:

```
public static String getString(Date d) {
   return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(d);
}
```

Comment: Does mysql have a conversion system from string to date?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Please refer here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html

Comment: @Desolator I didn't downvote, however you're not using the same date format as the question, and you removed the parameterization which was actually a very good idea.

Comment: So does that means I can use my code without any modification?

Comment: Yes. If you want to insert a date in a string format, use `setString`. If your date is `java.util.Date` then use `setString(1, getString(myDate))`

Answer (score -1):

Do like

```
insert into JsonData (last_crawl_date) values(DATE_FORMAT('2014/02/19','%Y-%m-%d'));
```