# JDBC not working as intended when inserting dates into Database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

my code seems to now work as intended and i can't seem to understand why . I'm trying to update a date from the database with anotherDate+14. The problem is all the updated dates have the same value. The code works when i try debugging it , but i got code different results in the db .
Here is the code :

```
String query="SELECT issueTime from issue";
    ResultSet rs=DatabaseHandler.getInstance().execQuery(query);
    try {
        while(rs.next()){
            java.sql.Date dbTime=rs.getDate("issueTime");
            java.sql.Date initialDBTime=dbTime;
            java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date(dbTime.getTime());
            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(utilDate);
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE,14);
            utilDate= cal.getTime();
            dbTime=new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
            System.out.println("return date " + dbTime+ " Initial db time " + initialDBTime);
           String qu = "UPDATE issue SET return_date=? WHERE issueTime = ?";
            PreparedStatement pstmt=DatabaseHandler.getInstance().getConnection().prepareStatement(qu);
            pstmt.setDate(1,dbTime);
            pstmt.setDate(2, initialDBTime);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Database results:

[image: Database results]

UPDATE : Found the problem , i was selecting only issueTime from my table . 
 Changed :

```
String query="SELECT * from issue";
```

Thank you for your help .

Comment: did you try committing?

Comment: just added commit to my code , it doesn't seem to work . maybe i'm doing it wrong

Comment: 'DatabaseHandler.getInstance().getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);
                PreparedStatement pstmt=DatabaseHandler.getInstance().getConnection().prepareStatement(qu);
                pstmt.setDate(1,dbTime);
                pstmt.setDate(2, initialDBTime);
                pstmt.executeUpdate();
                DatabaseHandler.getInstance().getConnection().commit();'

Comment: If you have important information to add, please [edit] your question instead of burying it in the comments.

Comment: Try using a primary or unique column in the where condition instead of date condition. I'm pretty sure the date column is not a Primary Key :-)

Comment: What's the time set to on the machine you're running this code on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872040/jdbc-inserting-date-values-into-mysql

Check this might be useful

Comment: Please don't add things like `[SOLVED]` to the title of your question. If you found a solution, post an **answer** describing that solution and accept that.

Comment: I already posted an UPDATE solved , but people where still replying.Sorry first time on stackoverflow.

Comment: Again, post an **answer**, don't obfuscate things by editing your solution into your **question**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Issuetime and return_date have DateTime format, try to use Timestamp instead of Date. Here an example if you want to add 14 days:

```
public class TestUpdate {


  public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
      TestsJdbc jdbc= new TestsJdbc();
      jdbc.connect();
      Connection con =jdbc.getConnection();
      List<java.sql.Timestamp> listIssueDate=getIssueDate(con );
      updateReturnDate(con, listIssueDate);
      jdbc.closeConnexion();

     }




  public static java.util.Date tmsToUtilDate(java.sql.Timestamp timestamp) {
        long milliseconds = timestamp.getTime() + (timestamp.getNanos() / 1000000);
        return new java.util.Date(milliseconds);
    }

  public static  java.sql.Timestamp getTimestamp(java.util.Date date){
      return date == null ? null : new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
    }




   public static java.util.Date addDay(java.util.Date curDate, int nbDay){
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       cal.setTime(curDate);
       cal.add(Calendar.DATE, nbDay); // add 10 days

       return cal.getTime();
   }




   public static List<java.sql.Timestamp>  getIssueDate(Connection connexion) throws SQLException{
    String  query="SELECT issueTime from issue";
    Statement statement;
    List<java.sql.Timestamp> listDate= new ArrayList<java.sql.Timestamp>();
        try {
            statement = (Statement) connexion.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery( query);
            while (rs.next()) {

                //java.sql.Time dbSqlTime = rs.getTime("issueTime");//only time
                //java.sql.Date dbSqlDate = rs.getDate("issueTime");//Date ex :YYYY-MM-DD
                java.sql.Timestamp dbSqlTimestamp = rs.getTimestamp("issueTime");// timestamp Date ex :YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
                System.out.println("date:"+dbSqlTimestamp);
                System.out.println();
                listDate.add(dbSqlTimestamp);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       return listDate;
   }

     public static void updateReturnDate(Connection connexion, List<java.sql.Timestamp> listIssueDate) throws SQLException
      {

          for(java.sql.Timestamp sqlIssueDate:listIssueDate){

              // 
              java.util.Date tempUtilDate=tmsToUtilDate(sqlIssueDate);
              java.util.Date newutilDate=addDay(tempUtilDate, 14);
              java.sql.Timestamp returnDate=getTimestamp(newutilDate);



              System.out.println(returnDate.getTime());
              System.out.println(sqlIssueDate);
             //Test
             String query="UPDATE issue SET return_date=? WHERE issueTime = ?";


              PreparedStatement preparedStmt = connexion.prepareStatement(query);
              preparedStmt.setTimestamp(1, returnDate);
              preparedStmt.setTimestamp(2, sqlIssueDate);

              // execute the java preparedstatement
              preparedStmt.executeUpdate();

          }
              //connexion.close();

      }
}
```

> a screenshot of table before:[image]
>
> the table after update :
>   [image]

Comment: I already solved the problem . Changing : `String query="SELECT issueTime from issue";`. to  `String query="SELECT * from issue";` solved the problem. Thank you for your answer

Comment: interested to know what was wrong, because the two queries give the same number of result. the diffrence is the number of column returned ( with * you return all the column of the table and not only issueTime)